# how to understand "what keyword had been searched to find a specific page of my website"?

Tags: search-engine

I wanna know what keyword was type in search engin textbox that leads the user to my website ...
it is pretty easy for google ... because it hold the search parameter in it's querystring and after redireting change it to destination ... (if u right clik on one of the items in google search list and 'Copy link address' you can see that keywords are in 'q' parameter).
but for other search engins like yahoo.com, bing.com, volunia.com (and the rest of sites mentioned  in this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines ) the querystring don't contain the keywords and it directly refer to a site. How can I find the user keywrod in all search engins?

Comment: Couldn't you look at the [`Referer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) and extract the query string?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

Have a Look on this  (free to sign up)

> http://www.google.co.in/webmasters/
>   and 
>   http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster

i assumes you want an API right ?
Google Analytics provides APIs to collect, configure, and report on user-interactions

The Clicky Analytics API can also help you

they provide you the  right  way to what else you want

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for google analytics!! Very easy to install and use.

Comment: Yes, it's one way. But I wanna use it in reporting part of a cms. is there any way that I get this data from google analytics?